# IE 7 Debug Issue - Script Error Popup

Tags: javascript, debugging, internet-explorer-7, cross-browser

I am building a site that will not work in IE6, intentionally. IE7 Is the oldest supported IE browser for my site.

I am having a problem in IE 7 when you arrive at my site.  A popup says: `Script Error Line 55 Char # Error: 'cms_ims' is undefined.` Then you have to press continue running scripts, yes.  Anyone know whats causing this in my code? My site is www.vitaminjdesign.com. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

try this one:

```
$(window).load(function(){

    var css_cims=[];   <<< add this one
    var css_ims=[];    <<< and this one

    $.each(css_ims,function(){(new Image()).src=_siteRoot+'css/images/'+this;});

    $.each(css_cims,function(){
         var css_im=this;
         $.each(['blue','purple','pink','red','grey','green','yellow','orange'],function(){
(new Image()).src=_siteRoot+'css/'+this+'/'+css_im;
    });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The variable `cms_ims` is not defined as either a global or local var in the executing function:

```
$(window).load(function(){
 $.each(css_ims,function(){(new Image()).src=_siteRoot+'css/images/'+this;});
 $.each(css_cims,function(){
  var css_im=this;
  $.each(['blue','purple','pink','red','grey','green','yellow','orange'],function(){
   (new Image()).src=_siteRoot+'css/'+this+'/'+css_im;
  });
 });
});
```

Comment: so what would I do? Delete it?

Comment: I did delete it, and it worked. You pointed it out so thanks!

Comment: Probably try to fix it, but I'm guessing you didn't write it. It looks like some kind of image preloader for a theme switcher or something.

Comment: yea i take that bac,, it didnt work.... i did not write that, it came with the jquery image slider plugin im using.   More of a pain than anything